# Emacs mode that highlight Lisp forms

Tags: emacs, lisp, mode

What is the Emacs mode or package that highlights Lisp forms changing the color of the backgrounds so that the form you are in has one color, the outer form another, the outer outer form another and so on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want to try [mwe-color-box](http://www.foldr.org/~michaelw/emacs/) (screenshot below) or read [Five approaches to s-expression highlighting](http://lemonodor.com/archives/001207.html) by [Lemondor](http://lemonodor.com/).

[image]
<sub>(source: [foldr.org](http://www.foldr.org/~michaelw/emacs/color-box.png))</sub>

Comment: http://lemonodor.com/index.php/2005/08/five_approaches/     (the new address for the now broken links in two answers)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at screenshots here http://lemonodor.com/archives/001207.html, may be that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use it, but this might be what you're looking for:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters